# Is it advisable to use :foreign_key in my migrations rather than just adding user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.2, I just want to know if there would be any difference if I use the `:foreign_key` keyword in my migrations rather than just adding a `user_id` column to add relationship to my models ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Rails need database-level constraints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589509/does-rails-need-database-level-constraints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## YES

The key difference is not on the application layer but on the database layer - foreign keys are used to make the database enforce referential integrity.

Lets look at an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If we declare `things.user_id` without a foreign key:

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord will happily allow us to orphan rows on the things table:

```
user = User.create(name: 'Max')
thing = user.things.create
user.destroy
thing.user.name # Boom! - 'undefined method :name for NilClass'
```

While if we had a foreign key the database would not allow us to destroy `user` since it leaves an orphaned record.

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
user = User.create(name: 'Max')
thing = user.things.create
user.destroy # DB says hell no
```

While you can simply regulate this with callbacks having the DB enforce referential integrity is usually a good idea.

```
# using a callback to remove associated records first
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Make sure you index the foreign key column -- you probably would anyway, but with a foreign key declared in the database it would be wise to make sure that you do. There is a gem which helps with that ... don't remember the name ...

Comment: I think you may be thinking of [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) however you don't need a gem to add foreign keys or indexes in a later migration -  and it is done anyways if you use the `belongs_to` macro when declaring the column http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys